# Date time and simple date time format results are different

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the following code fragment:

```
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"))
                .withYear(2016)
                .withMonthOfYear(8)
                .withDayOfMonth(25)
                .withHourOfDay(12)
                .withMinuteOfHour(37);

        System.out.println("DateTime: ");
        System.out.println(dateTime.toDate().getTime());

        String str = "2016-8-25 12:37 AM CST";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-M-dd hh:mm a z");

        System.out.println("SDF: ");
        try {
            System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).getTime()+"");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

According to my understanding, both represent the same Date (and hence the epoch should be the same as well). However the result I get is:

```
DateTime: 
1472146669119
SDF: 
1451198220000
```

If I change the timezone to CDT, then I get:

```
DateTime: 
1472146668746
SDF: 
1451194620000
```

So I hope some kind soul would enlighten me (to help this poor soul).

Thanks

Update:

I am using the following modified code:

```
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2016, 8, 25, 12, 37, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));

        System.out.println("DateTime: ");
        System.out.println(dateTime.toDate().getTime());

        String str = "2016-8-25 12:37 AM CDT";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a z");

        System.out.println("SDF: ");
        try {
            System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).getTime()+"");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I am getting:

```
DateTime: 
1472146620000
SDF: 
1472103420000
```

Comment: Sidenote: why are you using `YYYY` in your pattern?

Comment: you don't seem to be setting the TimeZone for the SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Good catch Sotirios!

Comment: 12 AM is `.withHourOfDay(0)`

Comment: Excellent!! That does it, Sotirios. Now I get identical results. Put your comment in an answer and I will mark it as as such. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second bit of code you posted, this date/time:

```
new DateTime(2016, 8, 25, 12, 37, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
//                         ^ - midday
```

...is 37 minutes after midday on 25 August 2016.

This date:

```
String str = "2016-8-25 12:37 AM CDT";
```

...is 37 minutes after midnight on 25 August 2016.

For the dates to match I expect the first one should be:

```
new DateTime(2016, 8, 25, 0, 37, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
//                        ^ - midnight
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).getTime()+"");
```

you are taking your formatted string, which does not include seconds, and parse it back into a date. The information regarding which second it was is lost, so the time is rounded to: 12:37:00.

Comment: That is what I want: 12:37:00